# These people showed up and closed a question I answered. What gives?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Help me fix my JavaScript quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556097/javascript-simple-quiz-help-needed/4556460#4556460)

the reason given: *it was not a question*, however I am very sure it was, and that my answer answered the question. I wasted considerable time trying to paste the code when I ran into a formatting issue when pasting code after a list, so when returning and seeing the question just closed like that, was a very unsatisfying event.
Thanks

Comment: "Closed" doesn't mean that your answer is no longer useful. All "closed" means is that no *new answers* can be added to the question.

Comment: Hmm, still seems a bit harsh. __I__ understood the question ;) I also expect a closed question cannot be accepted and earn any rep, right?

Comment: An answer to a closed question can still be accepted and earns rep for both votes and accept.

Comment: You do know that a question can be reopened yes? If you provide evidence here that it should be, then you may be able to sway people to reopen it. Also, once you pass the 20 cap you can go into Chat on MSO and those people tend to have VTC powers ;)  [PS this one is open again]

Comment: Great - thanks. The asker returned and needed more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question actually looks as clear to me as to you, but I believe the thing is that on quick first look it seems to be one of those "*give me teh codez*" questions. Since I have enough rep, I'll try to edit a bit to make it look more tolerable...

Comment: Yes, I agree on a quick look, however when I looked at the code, the main errors were a missing bracket and a reference to the form before the form existed. So very straight forward to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The question is not clear. There is no information about what the code is supposed to do or what the code actually does.

If you think you understand the question then please edit it to make it much clearer. If enough people can understand your edited version it can be reopened.

Comment: 1600 rep is not enough to allow me to edit it.
The question was crystal clear to me and so was the problem in the script.

Comment: mplungjan: If you don't have enough reputation then it is a good idea to leave a comment under the question telling the questioner what is wrong with the question and how to fix it. Remember that for the question to be useful to as many people as possible the question has to be clear to a wide audience, not just two people. Look at other good highly rated questions for ideas on how this one could be improved. Put the most important information (e.g. error messages, undesired behaviour) first, not buried deep in code fragments.

Comment: PS: I know it's not your question, but this site works because everyone takes on the responsibility for improving content, not just your own content but also other content that you can improve. As your reputation increases you will be given more trust to do this. Hopefully it won't be long before you have the required reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that, if you take time to write a good answer, it's harsh on you that the question is closed. Even more so if you wrote a good answer to a bad question! (And it would be yet even worse if the question was deleted.)

Maybe it should be somewhat more difficult to close questions that have answers? (as it is to delete them)

Comment: Yes, that would be cool if the people who answered a question that was about to be closed would have some say in this. Anyway, the question is reopened so I am satisfied. The asker did need help. And at least to me and a few others the problems with the code were very obvious and as such answerable without further ado

Comment: OK, so my vote for reopening was actually useful. First time it happens :)

Comment: Vote for re-open? Interesting. Where did that take place?

Comment: Same place as closing votes. Just below the question.

Comment: I want to split answers between you and Esko! Not possible it seems.
Aha - never noticed that